# Help wanted on \openout, \write and \closeout

Tags: conditionals, package-writing, write-file

Is there a way to test if a token is already associated with a `writer`? Something like this:

```
\def\do@write#1{%
  \immediate\write\mywriter{something: #1}%
}
\def\@writesomething#1{%
  {\if@isopen\mywriter{%
    \do@write{#1} }%
   {\immediate\openout\mywriter=myfile.txt%
    \do@write{#1} }%
  }
}
```

Where if `\mywriter` is not associated with an out-file, the `\openout` statement will be called; otherwise, be ignored.

Also is there any mechanism which would allow me to automatically close all open handles when LaTeX reaches the `\end{document}` statement?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no check on the open write streams. You always have to ensure that a write stream is open, before trying to write in it.

However you can emulate the check with a conditional:

```
\newif\if@mywriteopen % initially false

\def\@writesomething{%
  \if@mywriteopen\else
    \global\@mywriteopentrue
    \immediate\openout\mywriter=myfile.txt\relax
  \fi
  \do@write}
```

Notice that `\relax` after the file name should not be masked with a `%`, because TeX is expanding tokens when it's reading a file name; `\relax` will stop expansion, being unexpandable.

All the write and read streams are automatically closed at the end of a TeX run.

**Note.** There is no need to define `\@writesomething` with an argument, as long as `\do@write` is.

Comment: Could you explain the addition of `r`? I don't understand what is going on with `...mywriteopen...` versus `...mywriteropen...`. That is, you define `\if@mywriteropen` but then use `\if@mywriteopen`, `\@mywriteopentrue` etc.

Comment: @cfr Typos! :-(

Comment: Thanks. I was convinced this was some mystery into which I was not initiated! (Partly because this answer is not new and 'everyone else understood'.)